# What is the equivalent of !boolean (negative) on Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I have recently decided to switch from Java to Kotlin for Android Development. I don't know what to Google, so I'm asking here.

If we want to get the opposite of a boolean, we put a ! before it. Eg: I want the inside code to run only if the contains() returns false. How to do that?

Example, we do this in Java:

```
if (!string_text.contains(" "))
```

How do I write this in Kotlin?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-boolean/not.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`!` is the boolean not operator, same as Java.

Check https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/keyword-reference.html#operators-and-special-symbols

Answer (score -1):

Try

`if  (string_text.isNullOrBlank()) {`

[info oficial kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/is-null-or-blank.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).